# Is it possible to run exe at server by VBScript when request goes from NON IE browser

Tags: javascript, iis, vbscript, activex, windows-server-2003

can anybody tell me is it possible to run programs(.exe) by VBscript at server when request comes from NON IE browser. I am creating shell object as below.

```
Set WshShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Now i apply run method to execute the exe with command line options

Comment: Running executables on the server requires server-side code (in your scenario [ASP](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html)). Server-side code is (normally) transparent to the client.

Comment: yes that I am asking, IF file contain only vbscript code(means no html,no javascript and no css) then still it will be depend on IE browser or not. Actually I have to send some data to an asp page which contain only vbscript. Now I have to pass that data to a exe as commandline parameter. So doing this with WScript.shell run will be IE dependent or not.

Comment: I already answered your question. Now you need to understand how ASP (or server-side scripting in general) works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [launch an application from browser with parameters (cross browser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591439/launch-an-application-from-browser-with-parameters-cross-browser)