# launch an application from browser with parameters (cross browser)

Tags: javascript, parameters, cross-browser, activex, wsh

I am trying to launch an application from a webpage with parameters.
Activex shown below works only at IE.

```
MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );  
MyObject.Run('"C:\\Program Files\\application.exe" -guiparm=".." -system=..-client=..-user=.. -pw=..');  `
```

Is there any other way to do that cross browser?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Maybe a way like that with parameters <a href="file://C:/Windows/notepad.exe">Notepad</a>

Comment: Using file is blocked by Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
<a href="c:\windows\Notepad.exe" 
type="application/octet-stream">Launch Notepad</a>
```

From what I remember using file:// is blocked by Chrome and Firefox. I don't know how to send parameters but at least you can launch an application without using an ActiveXObject.

Comment: Nothing happens in any browser when I try this. Maybe it worked in IE versions less than 11.